# Reflexive, transitive, symmetric, and not asymmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to create a set of tuples out of the relation R = {1,2,3,4} that meets the above requirements. I am confused on how something could be symmetric, and not asymmetric? If someone could please explain that to me. My current answer: (1,2),(2,1),(1,1),(2,2). I am not quite sure exactly what I am doing although I understand the basic concepts of the relations. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is not reflexive..
I think the easiest relation satisfying the above is just $R \times R$ and that's it ;-)
There's also the empty relation, but I wouldn't use it in an exam or homework..